# Why searching in table view display blank table view after filtering data in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I search in table view, it gives correct array, I am using `NSPredicate` to filter array. Even while debugging I came to know, it goes to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and label is having data and everything is proper but as result there is only plain white default table view is shown, not the table which should be, after searching.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
preferredCustomCell *mycell = (preferredCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mycell.selectedBackgroundView.frame];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:189/255.f green:189/255.f blue:189/255.f alpha:0.25]];
[mycell setSelectedBackgroundView:backgroundView];
SearchbackView.hidden = YES;

// Configure the cell...
if (mycell == nil) {
    mycell = [[preferredCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

MyData *dealerData = Nil;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    dealerData = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    dealerData = [cellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

dealerInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@%@%@%@%@\n%@\n%@", dealerData.businessName, dealerData.address, dealerData.city,@", ", dealerData.state, @", ", dealerData.zip, dealerData.phone, dealerData.email];  // data.address;

mycell.dealerInfoLbl.text = dealerInfo;
mycell.dealerInfoLbl.numberOfLines = 0;

mycell.selectDealerBtn.tag = indexPath.row;

// Assign our own background image for the cell
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedCell"];
UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
cellBackgroundView.image = background;
mycell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
mycell.lblPreferred.hidden = YES;

if (mycell.selectDealerBtn.tag==btnTag) {
    if (selectDealer==true) {
        [mycell.selectDealerBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedDealer"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mycell.selectDealerBtn setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        mycell.selectDealerBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 16, 26, 17);
        mycell.selectDealerBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(32,-66, 0, 10);
        mycell.lblPreferred.hidden = NO;
    }
}
else{
    [mycell.selectDealerBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"N99-selectDealerBtn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mycell.selectDealerBtn setTitle:@"   " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    mycell.lblPreferred.hidden = YES;
}

return mycell;
```

Comment: Are you sure your array of searchedData is filled? Are you sure that array is alloc'd/init'd?

Comment: Try Log your search array before giving it to cell. Then you can see that is that filled or not?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus , Yes. I am sure. searchedData array is filled.

Comment: @yourwish , Yes. I have tried log. Array is filled.

Comment: @Aadhya Had you sets your delegates properly??

Comment: @yourwish, Yes I have set.

Comment: @Aadhya Then it`s Difficult to judge problem from here. Why don`t you use cell.contentview addsubview:YourView for giving custom view.

Comment: @yourwish, I can not do this, because this will allocate memory every time and my array contains 500 records and app will crash.

Comment: @Aaradhya Whats the deal of array in setting custom background view???

Comment: @yourwish, To match design.

Comment: @Aadhya Look at [THIS LINK](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/) Where Search Display Controller is Implemented Properly. Hope It can salve your issue :)

Comment: @yourwish,  I am following this link already.

Comment: @Aadhya, ha ha. Now I can just say that you need to filter every thing which is displaying in normal table. If you had already done it then problem is not with your search display controller.